# Imageview as togglebutton chnging its image in accordance as state get true or false?

Tags: android

saving the state as true and false in shared preference but imageview not changing to on as state get true ???

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_row, null); //activity_row.xml is your file.
    imageView2 = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.applist_item_image);
    preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    tgpref = preferences.getBoolean("tgpref", false);
    if (tgpref == true) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+tgpref, 500).show();
        imageView2.setImageResource(R.drawable.on);
    } else {
        imageView2.setImageResource(R.drawable.off);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+tgpref, 500).show();
    }

    String[] itemname = { "Wi-Fi", "Bluetooth", "Mobile Data",};
    Integer[] imgid = { R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher, };
    mListView2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvAppList1);

    final RowActivity adapter = new RowActivity(this, itemname, imgid);
    mListView2.setAdapter(adapter);
            mListView2.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
                    imageView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.applist_item_image);
                    if (switches==R.drawable.on) {
                        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.on);
                        preferences.edit().putBoolean("tgpref", true).commit();
                        switches = R.drawable.off;
                    } else {`enter code here`
                        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.off);
                        preferences.edit().putBoolean("tgpref", false).commit();
                        switches = R.drawable.on;
                    }}});
        }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by xml and code like following

make xml like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- Remember: order is important. First matching state(s) is rendered) -->
<item 
    android:state_selected="true" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/yeah" />
<item 
    android:drawable="@drawable/yeah2" />
```

Then in Java do following

```
imageButton.setImageDrawable(getBaseContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ImageButton));

//set the click listener
imageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View button) {
    //Set the button's appearance
    button.setSelected(!button.isSelected());

    if (button.isSelected()) {
        //Handle selected state change
    } else {
        //Handle de-select state change
    }

}

});
```

Comment: but i hv to toggle imageview in listview and then saving state and after application starts ...imgaeview change according to saved state..?